# Nothing gets drawn as soon as GL_DEPTH_TEST is enabled

Tags: qt, opengl

As soon as I set glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) in the following code, nothing except for the clear color gets drawn on screen.

**window.cpp**

```
void Window::initializeGL() {
    makeCurrent();
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.03f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

    Shaders::initShaders();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    currentLevel.addTiles();

    viewMatrix.setToIdentity();
    viewMatrix.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -8.0f);
    viewMatrix.rotate(45.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void Window::resizeGL(int width, int height) {
    const float fov = 45.0f,
          zNear = 0.0f,
          zFar = 1000.0f;

    projectionMatrix.setToIdentity();
    projectionMatrix.perspective(fov, width / float(height), zNear, zFar);
}

void Window::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    currentLevel.setProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
    currentLevel.setViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
    currentLevel.draw();
}
```

**tile.cpp:**

```
// Constructor with custom shader
Tile::Tile(QVector3D v1, QVector3D v2, QVector3D v3, QVector3D v4, QOpenGLShaderProgram* shaderProgram) :
    vbo(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer),
    cbo(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer),
    ibo(QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer) {

    // Calculate surface normal & second set of vertices
    QVector3D surfaceNormal = QVector3D::normal(v1, v2, v3);
    QVector3D v1_n = v1 - surfaceNormal;
    QVector3D v2_n = v2 - surfaceNormal;
    QVector3D v3_n = v3 - surfaceNormal;
    QVector3D v4_n = v4 - surfaceNormal;

    // Set up rectangular mesh from given corner vectors
    vertices = {
        v1, v2, v3, v4,
        v1_n, v2_n, v3_n, v4_n
    };

    colors = {
        color1, color1, color2, color2,
        color1, color1, color2, color2
    };

    indices = {

        // Face 1
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,

        // Face 2
        0, 4, 5,
        5, 1, 0,

        // Face 3
        4, 5, 6,
        6, 7, 4

    };

    this->shaderProgram = shaderProgram;

    cacheShaderLocations();
    createBuffers();
}

Tile::~Tile() {
    vbo.destroy();
    vao.destroy();
    ibo.destroy();
}

// Cache Uniform Locations for shaders
void Tile::cacheShaderLocations() {
    positionLocation = shaderProgram->attributeLocation("position");
    colorLocation = shaderProgram->attributeLocation("color");
    modelLocation = shaderProgram->uniformLocation("model");
    viewLocation = shaderProgram->uniformLocation("view");
    projectionLocation = shaderProgram->uniformLocation("projection");
}

// Create buffers
void Tile::createBuffers() {

    // Vertex Buffer Object
    vbo.create();
    vbo.bind();
    vbo.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    vbo.allocate(vertices.constData(), vertices.size() * sizeof(QVector3D));
    vbo.release();

    // Color Buffer Object
    cbo.create();
    cbo.bind();
    cbo.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    cbo.allocate(colors.constData(), colors.size() * sizeof(QVector3D));
    cbo.release();

    // Index Buffer Object
    ibo.create();
    ibo.bind();
    ibo.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    ibo.allocate(indices.constData(), indices.size() * sizeof(GLushort));
    ibo.release();

    // Vertex Array Object
    vao.create();

    // Setup buffer attributes
    shaderProgram->bind();
    vao.bind();
    vbo.bind();
    shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(positionLocation);
    shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(positionLocation, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 0);
    cbo.bind();
    shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(colorLocation);
    shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer(colorLocation, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 0);
    ibo.bind();
    vao.release();

    // Release buffers & shader program
    vbo.release();
    cbo.release();
    ibo.release();
    shaderProgram->release();
}

void Tile::draw() {
    shaderProgram->bind();

    // Send uniforms to shader
    shaderProgram->setUniformValue(projectionLocation, projectionMatrix);
    shaderProgram->setUniformValue(viewLocation, viewMatrix);
    shaderProgram->setUniformValue(modelLocation, modelMatrix);

    // Draw vertices
    vao.bind();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    vao.release();

    shaderProgram->release();
}
```

As for the depth buffer itself, according to the Qt documentation it's enabled by default. In the main.cpp I set the surface format/context like this:

```
  // Set OpenGL Version information
  QSurfaceFormat format;
  format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
  format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
  format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
  format.setVersion(3,3);
```

I really have no clue why nothing gets drawn when I try to use depth testing so I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Unrelated, but under Core profile you cannot bind an index (element) buffer without a VAO bound. The index buffer binding point is part of the VAO state.

Comment: What's in the shaders? Change the shaders, so they draw certain color, depending on the z coordinate. Change `glDepthFunc` to something different.

Comment: Will try that as soon as I'm home. I just noticed my zNear is set to 0.0, could that cause the problem?

Comment: "zNear = 0.01f" solved it.

Comment: @peppe That's only partly true. Yes, the binding is part of the VAO state. But it's still legal to bind it without a VAO bound.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: it is **illegal** to bind a buffer to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding point without a VAO bound. Any modification or query of the vertex array state is illegal without a VAO bound (GL 4.5, §10.3.1). The buffer bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is part of the vertex array state (§10.3.10, §23.4). An unofficial reference is also here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers

Comment: @peppe This was discussed before. The only thing that really counts is the spec. While it sends a somewhat mixed message, the most conclusive evidence is that the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING` can be queried for a VAO with `GetVertexArrayiv()` (page 358 of 4.5 spec), which gives the binding stored in a VAO, as well as with `glGetIntegerv()` (page 361), which gives the current binding without specifying a VAO. Also, what you're suggesting is not listed as an error condition for `BindBuffer()`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: sure, you can query the element array buffer (stored in the VAO) in two different ways. Still, the mere act of binding a buffer to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` point is touching part of the Vertex Array state (§23.4, pag. 561 of the 4.5 spec), and §10.3.1 pag. 333 clearly says "An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated by any commands which modify, draw from, or query vertex array state when no vertex array is bound.". To put it otherwise: what sense would it make to allow a binding that modifies vertex array state without having a VAO bound? Why using VAOs at all then?

Comment: @peppe I don't really feel like arguing this any longer. You're free to your own interpretation. As another input, check out the OpenGL tutorial by Nicol Bolas: http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html#d0e5113: "glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER): Calling this without a VAO bound will not fail." It's useful to bind an index buffer without having a VAO bound to fill it with data.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: well, it's always good to have technical arguments :) I've raised the issue to Khronos iself. https://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1508

Comment: @vigilanum: you can answer your own question, by the way.